# Amazon Lex Response Error "Too Many Requests"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

I'm trying to integrate Amazon Lex with a web app, based on this example (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-browser-audio-capture/tree/master/example).

But after 4-5 successful statements, I'm getting a response with 429 (Too Many Requests) with an error:

> error Error: You are sending requests at an excessive rate

After couple more requests I am getting:

> error Error: Invalid Request: Exceeded maximum speech duration of 15000 millis

I see in the response object that `inputTranscript` is aggregating all audio together. For example, if I made audio requests like "Open item", "Open can", "Show something", then `inputTranscript` is:

```js
inputTranscript: "open item open can show something"
```

But `slots` is correct: it shows only the last one:

```js
slots: {
  word: "show something"
}
```

I feel I'm missing a cleaning/resetting step between the requests. But I wasn't able to find any documentation about cleaning up before you make a request.